# SQL Server: compare dates by only matching month and day

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that fetches records based on dates matching a date input which works fine so far. 
Both the dates in the table and my input date are formatted as datetime.

Instead of comparing the full dates I would like to change this so that it only compares month and day so that it works with any year for the input.

**Example:** 
A date in the table is saved as `2013-04-30` and my input date is `2014-04-30`. 
What I want is that the stored procedure still returns that record independent of the year as long as month and day match.

**My stored procedure:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchDays]
    @inputDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT      dateID,
                dayDT,
                countries,
                regions
    FROM        DaysDT
    WHERE       dayDT = @inputDate
    FOR XML PATH('daysFixed'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('root')

END
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Mike.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do something like this ;)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchDays]
    @inputDate datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT      dateID,
                dayDT,
                countries,
                regions
    FROM        DaysDT
    WHERE       
        DAY(dayDT) = DAY(@inputDate) --Extract and compare day
        AND MONTH(dayDT) = MONTH(@inputDate) --Extract and compare month
    FOR XML PATH('daysFixed'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('root')

END
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is perfect ! Will accept as soon as possible. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
WHERE datepart(day, dayDT) = datepart(day,@inputDate)
AND datepart(month, dayDT) = datepart(month,@inputDate)
```

This will compare the date and month parts of your overall date, without checking the year.

Comment: Thanks, this is it - the other post was just a few seconds faster.

Comment: No worries, the important thing is that you acknowledge whoever took their time to help, and that the answer given will be a good resource for others with a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have been needed this type of requirement in past. I have used this solution and it worked for me as I wanted.

```
SELECT * FROM yourTableName
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(yourColumnName, '%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT('yourValue', '%m-%d') and yourOtherCondition;
```

Comment: With a bit of tweeking for SQL server this answer worked for me +1 

`WHERE FORMAT([birthday], 'dd-MM') = FORMAT(CAST(GETDATE() as date), 'dd-MM')`